# Spring boot WAR deployed to Tomcat ignored code after SpringApplication.run()

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, tomcat, runtime

I am developing a web application for my bachelor thesis on university.
I am experiencing a very disturbing behavior from Tomcat. Although I fixed all issues running a WAR on real Tomcat 9.0.34 (lastest version 9) vs on embedded Tomcat 9.0.31 from "spring-boot-starter-tomcat" dependency which occurred so far, this issue is mysterious to me.
None of the code (I also tried `System.Out.println(...)` or `logger.info(...)` which is after the line `SpringApplication.run(...)`, is executed when the WAR is deployed to Tomcat server.

The code however ***is*** executed when run using embedded Tomcat container (e.g. through `java -jar app.war`)
In my pom.xml maven settings, Tomcat is marked in scope "runtime", so both real and embedded Tomcat options are available for the WAR.
My application is run through this main:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.me.myProject"})
@ServletComponentScan
public class MySpringWebApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer /* needed for WAR packaging */ { 

...public static void main(String[] args){
    ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(MySpringWebApplication.class, args);
    DatabaseSeeder sampleDataSeeder = new DatabaseSeeder(ctx.getBean(UserDAO.class), ctx.getBean(RegisterService.class), ctx.getBean(LibraryDAO.class));
    sampleDataSeeder.ensureSampleLibraryExistence(); //this code is not executed in real Tomcat
    sampleDataSeeder.ensureSampleLibraryExistence(); //this code isn't either
    sampleDataSeeder.ensureSampleLibraryExistence(); //I spammed more of this to checkthat it really didn't happen
    sampleDataSeeder.ensureSampleLibraryExistence();
    sampleDataSeeder.ensureSampleLibraryExistence();
    sampleDataSeeder.ensureSampleLibraryExistence();
    EmailService service = ctx.getBean(EmailService.class);
    service.sendEmailToMaintainer("end of main reached", "some text"); //this email is  never sent on real Tomcat but always sent on embedded Tomcat
}}
```

I cannot seed the database data before the spring context is initialized because it initializes my services etc.

Do you have any idea what could possibly be the case there?
 Thank you for any advice!

Jan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do something after application run... There is two way to do this:

#### Way 1:

implement CommandLineRunner and implement run method..

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.me.myProject"})
@ServletComponentScan
public class MySpringWebApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements CommandLineRunner /* needed for WAR packaging */ { 
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(MySpringWebApplication.class, args);
         //this email is  never sent on real Tomcat but always sent on embedded Tomcat
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        DatabaseSeeder sampleDataSeeder = new DatabaseSeeder(ctx.getBean(UserDAO.class), ctx.getBean(RegisterService.class), ctx.getBean(LibraryDAO.class));
        sampleDataSeeder.ensureSampleLibraryExistence(); //this code is not executed in real Tomcat
        sampleDataSeeder.ensureSampleLibraryExistence(); //this code isn't either
        sampleDataSeeder.ensureSampleLibraryExistence(); //I spammed more of this to checkthat it really didn't happen
        sampleDataSeeder.ensureSampleLibraryExistence();
        sampleDataSeeder.ensureSampleLibraryExistence();
        sampleDataSeeder.ensureSampleLibraryExistence();
        EmailService service = ctx.getBean(EmailService.class);
        service.sendEmailToMaintainer("end of main reached", "some text");
    }
}
```

#### Way 2:

implement ApplicationRunner..

```
@Component
public class AppRunner implements ApplicationRunner {
    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
      //do after application running
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! 
The ApplicationRunner with ApplicationContext injected through constructor (@Autowired) works just as I needed!

Answer (score 1):

When deploying your application to a Tomcat container, your main method is not run. Tomcat has its own entry point from the operating system and you method is not called.

SpringBootServletInitializer has a configure method you can override, but it looks like you're trying to load some data before the application starts. I would recommend removing that from the application and into a script of its own as you will be initializing that data each time the application starts.